# IntelliJ IDEA: how change the color of a variable?

Tags: intellij-idea

```java
public static void main (String [] args) {
  int Sun = 60;
}
```

How to change the color of `Sun`?

Now in IntelliJ IDEA it is grey, but I want to change it to orange.

Answer (score 0):

Grey is a color of the unused symbol: Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Color Scheme | General | Errors and Warnings | Unused code.

Once your variable is actually used in the code, its color will change to Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Color Scheme | Language Defaults | Identifiers | Local variable.

Comment: I try to change colour in local varible, but it still stay in grey

Comment: That is because your variable is unused and `Unused code` setting is used as explained in my answer.